# Terminal - Incorrect cyrillic characters display on vi/vim

Tags: macos, terminal, encoding, vi

If i open any file in vim with cyrillic characers - most of them a shown like `?~A ?~B ?~C`
[image]
Displaying by any other console utility like less or cat works just fine.
[image]
Problem occurs in vim both locally and on remote server via SSH. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Problem was because locale wasn't set

```
❯ locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

And it wasn't set because encoding wasn't properly set in vim to utf-8

```
:set expandtab?
latin-1
```

It in its turn was because I had unticked Terminal option "Set local environment variables on startup", had some bug with it before.
[image: Terminal option]

So the solution is to turn it on back or add to ~/.bash_rc or ~/.zshrc configs

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

or

```
export LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="ru_RU.UTF-8"
```

I've chosen the latter and now it works.